# Node Restify request ESOCKETTIMEDOUT before default 2 minutes has been reached

Tags: node.js, https, restify

I have a node restify server and I am mainly using it for verifying image urls are valid. I get a lot of `ESOCKETTIMEDOUT` errors for valid image urls. I was using the request module, which has a default of `5000ms` for requests, which is just fine for me. But other issues led me to switch to the node https module. From what I can see in my research, I can modify the restify default of 2 minutes by doing something like `server.server.setTimeout(300000)`.

My questions are simply:

1. Would this even resolve my issue? I think not as the default of 2 minutes is more than enough for what I'm doing.
2. Is this even the incorrect setting that I am looking at? Is there something else to set the request timeout for node https requests within restify?

Here is my basic server:

```
const server = restify.createServer({
  formatters: {
    'text/html': function htmlFormatter(req, res, body) {
      let data = '';
      if (body) {
        data = body.toString();
      }

      res.setHeader('Content-Length', Buffer.byteLength(data));
      return data;
    }
  }
});
```

Here is my request example:

```
const options = {
  host: parsed.host,
  path: parsed.path,
  timeout: 5000
};
https.get(options, (res) => {
  let body = [];
  res.on('data', (data) => {
    body.push(data);
  });
  res.on('end', () => {
    //do whatever
  });
})
```

Comment: Can you clarify? How can you go from trying to use the request module to using a server to do the same thing?

Comment: @HeadCode Not sure what you mean. But to clarify, I was always using a node restify server, but for verifying image urls I used the request module, which I could the set the timeout on by doing something like `const request = require('request').defaults({timeout:5000})`. So, due to other issues with the request module, I decided to switch to the node https request, and want to know how to set a new timeout for this, similar to what I had done with the request module. I posted the restify code, as this is important in this question, and could impact the answer.

Comment: The server has nothing to do with your question. Can you post the request code?

Comment: @HeadCode The server was posted due to suggested solution in the question. I have updated to show the basic request being used, which needs the timeout to be appropriately assigned.